# more matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

Related to a previous question: Suppose I want to invert a (sparse) matrix written in block form as
\begin{array}{cccc}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \ldots & A_{1n}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} &  & \vdots\\
\vdots &  & \ddots\\
A_{n1} & A_{n2} & \ldots & A_{nn}
\end{array}

where all the $A_{i,j}$'s are diagonal. Is the best way to do this just repeated application of the partitioned matrix inverse formula? Also, do such matrices have a name?

Comment: Yes, they are called matrices. Isn't every matrix of that form, with the submatrices $1\times1$?

Comment: Let me add the qualifier of sparseness then.

Comment: If they don't have a name yet, I'd call them "striped matrices"...

Answer (score 3):

If the $A_{ij}$ are $m \times m$ diagonal blocks, then your matrix rearranges into 
$m$ diagonal blocks, each $n \times n$, by the permutation of row and column indices 
$1 + a + b m \mapsto 1 + b + a n$, $a= 0 \ldots m-1,\ b = 0 \ldots n-1$.  So just invert each diagonal block and permute back.  For example
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} a_{{1,1}}&0&0&a_{{1,4}}&0&0\\ 0 &a_{{2,2}}&0&0&a_{{2,5}}&0\\ 0
&0&a_{{3,3}}&0&0&a_{{3,6}}\\a_{{4,1}}&0&0&a_{{4,4}}
&0&0\\ 0&a_{{5,2}}&0&0&a_{{5,5}}&0
\\ 0&0&a_{{6,3}}&0&0&a_{{6,6}}\end {array} \right]^{-1} = \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} b_{{1,1}}&0&0&b_{{1,4}}&0&0\\ 0&b_{{2,2}}&0&0&b_{{2,5}}&0\\ 0
&0&b_{{3,3}}&0&0&b_{{3,6}}\\b_{{4,1}}&0&0&b_{{4,4}}
&0&0\\ 0&b_{{5,2}}&0&0&b_{{5,5}}&0
\\ 0&0&b_{{6,3}}&0&0&b_{{6,6}}\end {array} \right]$$ 
where $$\left[\matrix{b_{11} & b_{14}\cr b_{41} & b_{44}\cr}\right] = 
\left[\matrix{a_{11} & a_{14}\cr a_{41} & a_{44}\cr}\right]^{-1},\ 
\left[\matrix{b_{22} & b_{25}\cr b_{52} & b_{55}\cr}\right] = 
\left[\matrix{a_{22} & a_{25}\cr a_{52} & a_{55}\cr}\right]^{-1},\
\left[\matrix{b_{33} & b_{36}\cr b_{63} & b_{66}\cr}\right] = 
\left[\matrix{a_{33} & a_{36}\cr a_{63} & a_{66}\cr}\right]^{-1}$$